# Декоратор не выводит значение

Tags: javascript

```js
function f(x) {
  alert(x)
}

function debounce(func, ms) {

  let isCooldown = false;

  return function(x) {
    if (isCooldown) return;

    func.apply(this, arguments);

    isCooldown = true;

    setTimeout(() => isCooldown = false, ms);
  };
}

let f = debounce(f, 1000);

f(1);
f(2);
```

Должно выводить 1, 2 спустя 1000ms, но ничего не выводит, в чем ошибка?

Comment: "в чем ошибка?" - `Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'f' has already been declared`

Comment: "Должно выводить" - где?

Comment: @igor исправил в первой функции, добавил `alert(x)`

Comment: @NickRoddy очень странная конструкция, она не будет работать. Ну и подсказать что то невозможно, так как не понятно что из этого можно выкинуть,  а что нельзя. Есть у вас текст задачи?

Answer (score 0):

Во первых у вас ошибка декларации, поэтому код не работает.

Во вторых У вас код не будет выводиться 1 и 2 через время, так как вы его не вызываете в таймауте, а перед ним.

В третьих у вас выводится 1, потом вы меняете isCooldown = true; и запускаете вторую функцию, которая не будет ждать таймаут. Во второй функции условие не выполняется и она сразу прекращает работу.

Если напишите, что нужно сделать, то можно будет помочь, а так не понятно зачем такие конструкции.